# How do I query a MongoDB collection?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 5090ace3788a466769b3804e
)
[startdate] => MongoDate Object (
    [sec] => 1301616000
    [usec] => 0
)
[enddate] => MongoDate Object (
    [sec] => 1304121600
    [usec] => 0
)
[your_id] => 33902
[odd_blah] => blahblah
[cam_id] => 339
[cost] => 0.01
[iscurrent] => 
[damn_current] => Array (
)

$coll = $this->mongo_db->where('cam_id', 339)->get('collection_name);
```

This returns nothing. As you might notice I am using
https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2

I get an empty array. Can anyone help? This sounds primitive, but kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, you need to put your `where` statement in an array.

```
$coll = $this->mongo_db
    ->where(array('cam_id' => 339))
    ->get('collection_name');
```

I'm assuming you're using Alex Bilbie's [MongoDB CodeIgniter Library](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library). His documentation is really out of date and it is more recommended to look at the comments of his [source code](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php) for examples and the types of inputs that the functions require.

Comment: Well, I did refer to the source documentation. The method check if the first argument is an associative array of field and value.


public function where($wheres = array(), $value = NULL)
{
if (is_array($wheres))
{
foreach ($wheres as $where => $value)
{
$this->wheres[$where] = $value;
}
}

else
{
$this->wheres[$wheres] = $value;
}

return $this;
}

Used your method too, still no luck.